# for the data-driven feature, doest it support an normal array looping, not json array?

Tags: karate

I need to loop a string (split by ',')  and get each element passed to the feature files automatically. I know there is excellent support for json array data-driven test, but does it support data-driven with normal strings or string array

As I know, I need to get it converted to a json array to support data-driven test at runtime, however, I want to know any existing support for normal array looping directly and automatically.

Here is my string(separated by ',') that needs to get passed as request parameter:

```
   "PHE,TSH,17_a_OHP,G6PD,MSMS,THALASSEMIA,DGT"
```

Because my string is dynamically produced at runtime, I want to loop it automatically and pass to other feature files, not manually,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [converting arrays into other "shapes"](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms) is easy in Karate. And in 0.9.3 we introduced the `karate.mapWithKey()` API, so you can do this:

```
* def string = 'PHE,TSH,17_a_OHP,G6PD,MSMS,THALASSEMIA,DGT'
* def array = string.split(',')
* def list = karate.mapWithKey(array, 'name')
* print list
```

So you can see, `list` is ready to use for data-driven features. Also note that you can use this in [dynamic scenario outlines](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline) !