# Call feature in a loop and have one variable in the called feature as iteration number

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, karate

I am calling the feature (which has some validations) in the loop N number of times. This code works and calls my feature  3 times.

```
* def xxx =
    """
      function(times){
         for(i=0;i<times;i++){
          karate.call('classpath:api/test/hello.feature');
        }
      }
    """

* call xxx 3
```

In the feature file I am calling, first line of code is:

```
* def someVariable = 0;
* def index = response[someVariable]
* some other code
```

I need `someVariable` to change based on the `i` index. For example, in the loop, first time feature is called `* def someVariable = 0;`Second time it is called `* def someVariable = 1;` Third time it is called `* def someVariable = 2;`

How can this be achieved? Or can I add this variable inside the JS loop? Or, maybe __loop can be used (looked at the examples, but was not able to implement it). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try passing the index as an argument while calling the feature file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer (not recommended):

```
karate.call('classpath:api/test/hello.feature', { someVariable: i });
```

Recommended approach, read this part of the docs (if you can): https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

Then read these answers also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56599134/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60853173/143475

Comment: Thanks for taking time sharing the solutions. i really appreciate it.  First one works fine for my scenario, and that's exactly what I was looking for. I will review other ways as well, I have seen those solutions before, but they looked more complex to me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am not understanding correctly but why dont just pass the index variable to someVariable like

```
for(i=0;i<times;i++){
   someVariable = i
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I wanted, for some reason it did not work. Peter shared a solution karate.call('classpath:api/test/hello.feature', { someVariable: i }) and it does work like that.